# Compile Error Sub or Function not defined

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been struggling with this issue for a while. This is my first question to stackoverflow. I am developing an Access report that uses a Dialog Form for the user to enter the specific client to be displayed on report. I have been able to print out report but am unable to handle if user enters "Cancel" on Dialog Form. I have copied code from an existing report in another Access database.

This my Report_Open Sub:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)  
' Set public variable to true to indicate that the report  
' is in the Open even   
   bInReportOpenEvent = True  

 ' Open Appt Query Dialog  
   DoCmd.OpenForm "craid CMM Client Report Dialog", , , , , acDialog  

 ' Cancel Report if User Clicked the Cancel Button    
   If IsLoaded("craid CMM Client Report Dialog") = False Then Cancel = True  

' Set public variable to false to indicate that the    
' Open event is completed    
  bInReportOpenEvent = False  

End Sub
```

When I run this, I am getting "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" highlighting the word "IsLoaded". I am able to comment out the IsLoaded line of code, but then I get an error if I click "Cancel" on Dialog Form.

I have seen this error in previous questions, but have been unable to determine a solution for my needs. Any help appreciated.

Laura

Comment: IsLoaded in not a standard VBA function. You copied your code from elsewhere, and in this elsewhere there was a custom IsLoaded function that you had to copy too.

Comment: Also, please show the code that triggers the report to open. It is a button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Thomas in the comments, `IsLoaded` is not a standard VBA function and so the compiler will search within the scope of evaluation and all public modules for a Sub or Function named `IsLoaded`, and will report an error if no such Sub or Function is found.

Assuming that your function merely returns a boolean value to determine whether or not a form with the supplied name is open, the function definition may look something like the following:

```vb
Function IsLoaded(strNme As String) As Boolean
    IsLoaded = CurrentProject.AllForms(strNme).IsLoaded
End Function
```

Copying the above definition either to your Report module, or to a public module should resolve the error that you are facing. However, you should ideally source the code for the original definition of your function.

Comment: Another style of check along those lines can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41059276/4717755)

Comment: I added the Function definition that you suggested and that solved the problem. It is now compiling cleanly and also handling the Cancel button in my Dialog Form.  Thanks for the assistance.  I looked all over the original report to try to find a definition for IsLoaded, but found nothing.